# pre-loading data using LSAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way to pre-load data into local storage when using the LSAdapter.  If using the FixtureAdapter, I would just set the FIXTURES property of model to the JSON I want to pre-load.  Is there similar capability in the LSAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

Just push data into local storage before you call find using the lsadapter.  It's essentially the same idea as setting it in the FIXTURES property.

localStorage.setItem('key', 'item');

Comment: I think he's using the LocalStorage adapter, not accessing the localStorage directly.

Comment: localStorage is the 'FIXTURES' of the LocalStorage adapter.

Comment: Yes, but you would be coupling the key and format, so it's better to normalize the data and then call save as I my example above. The key would normally be something like `DS.LSAdapter` and the value JSON like `{"App.MyModel":{"records":{"key":"value"...`

Comment: Good point, it's probably better to be loosely coupled in the event that ED changes its format.

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing this on my application route beforeModel hook. The trick is to call `pushMany` on the store and then `save` on each instance. Both steps are needed because push adds them to the store and save is needed to add them to Local Storage, so next time you don't have to preload them.

```
  var ApplicationRoute, refreshData, refreshDataFor;

  ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function() {
      return refreshData(this.store);
    }
  });

  refreshData = function(store) {
    return refreshDataFor(App.YourModel, store);
  };

  refreshDataFor = function(model, store) {
    model.store = store;
    return $.getJSON('your/url/here', function(instances) {
      return store.pushMany(model, instances).forEach(function(instance) {
        return instance.save();
      });
    });
  };
```

Also, we usually have an updated_at attribute in the models. I get the last one and send that to the server so we only get deltas. If your models are a bit more static, you could reuse your FIXTURES properties (as used from in the FixtureAdapter) and simply loop through them as I mentioned here. `pushmany` will update them if needed.

Comment: This isn't Fixture Data, you're just fetching data (from the server) and saving it into local storage.  But you're doing this every time your application restarts, which gives you the exact same benefit as just using the RESTadapter.

Comment: I agree about the restarts, updating the answer